# Query for Multiple records showing as a single line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table, Table Contains lot of records with lot of Applicant Unique Number,

```
SINo , ApplUniqNo, Amount, PaymentId,Year
1,         203,   2583.02,   1,   2014-15
2,         307,   1254.25,   2,   2014-15
3,         203,   2413.50,   2,   2014-15
4,         203,   5689.32,   1,   2014-15
```

The Above table showing same records ApplUniqNo:203,
My Requirment is display like this

```
ApplUniqNo,Amount,PaymentId
203, 2583.02/2413.50/5689.32 ,1/2/1
```

Could you please Help me. write a Query for Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FOR XML` for this

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
     ApplUniqNo
    ,(SELECT 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,Amount)+'/' from @TempTable Amounts WHERE Amounts.ApplUniqNo = YourTable.ApplUniqNo
        FOR XML PATH('')   )  AS Amount
 ,(SELECT 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,PaymentId)+'/' from @TempTable PaymentIds WHERE PaymentIds.ApplUniqNo = YourTable.ApplUniqNo
    FOR XML PATH(''))  AS PaymentID
FROM
    YourTable
)

SELECT
    ApplUniqNo
    ,SUBSTRING(Amount,0,LEN(Amount)) AS Amount
    ,SUBSTRING(PaymentID,0,LEN(PaymentID)) AS PaymentID
FROM 
    CTE
```

The common table expression is used to remove the last extra '/' using substring